# Find next first row meeting a condition after a specific row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```py
    first   second
0   True    False
1   False   True
2   True    True
3   False   False
4   False   True
5   False   True
6   True    False
7   False   False
```

that could be created with the code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'first': [True, False, True, False, False, False, True, False], 
        'second': [False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False]
    }
)
```

For any row having a `True` value in the ***first*** column, I want to find the first row in the next rows where the value of ***second*** column is `True`.

So the output should be:

```py
    first   second
1   False   True
4   False   True
```

Also, it's my priority not to use any for-loops.

Have you any idea about this?

Comment: Should it reset on each first True? For instance if 1/second was False, should 2 match or not?

Comment: Yes, it should reset. So if 1/second was ```False```, 2 wasn't in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
g = df['first'].ne(df['first'].shift()).cumsum().loc[~df['first']]
# or
# g = df['first'].cumsum()[~df['first']]

out = df[df['second']].groupby(g).head(1)
```

Output:

```
   first  second
1  False    True
4  False    True
```

Intermediate grouper `g`:

```
1    2
3    4
4    4
5    4
7    6
Name: first, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not to ask a new question, what if it should reset on each first ```True```? For instance, if 1/second was ```False```, 2 should match. (exactly your question :) )

Comment: @mozway can you explain the logic for this code?
Thanks

Comment: @GopalChitalia sure, make groups starting on each True for "first" (see `g` in my answer), for each of these groups, only keep the rows in which there is True in "second" and get the first row of the group. You can actually make it a bit more simple, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Another way without `groupby`:

```
out = (df.loc[df.loc[df.any(axis=1), 'first'].shift(fill_value=False)
         .loc[lambda x: x].index])
print(out)

# Output
   first  second
1  False    True
4  False    True
```

Note: It only works because there is always one True value from `second` column between two True values from `first` column.

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

```
first_true_idx = df.loc[df['first']].index
second_true_idx = df.loc[df['second']].index
df = df.loc[second_true_idx[list(filter(
     lambda x:x>=0, [(second_true_idx  > e).tolist().index(True) 
                if (second_true_idx > e).any() else -1 for e in first_true_idx]))]]
```

print(df):

```
first  second
1  False    True
4  False    True
```

I believe it should work for whatever position True values are in 'second'
Basically I try to look for first greater index in second true index for every index in first true index. This is what you are asking exactly.