# How to get the timestamp of the next row meeting a condition after a specific row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a df with columns 't' for time, 'first' and 'second'. (Here I used numbers in the t column for simplicity but they will be datetime objects or date strings)

```
t   first   second
1   grey    red
2   green   red
3   red     red
4   grey    green
5   green   red
6   grey    green
7   green   red
8   red     red
```

It can be created like this:

```
import pandas as pd

dfx = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'time': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
        'first': ['grey', 'green', 'red', 'grey', 'green', 'grey', 'green', 'red'], 
        'second': ['red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'red']
    }
)
```

I need to select rows where first equals to green and then add the next time where second equals to green also. The resulting df would look like this:

```
t   first   t_second
2   green   4
5   green   6
7   green   NaN
```

How could I achieve this?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73057952/find-next-first-row-meeting-a-condition-after-a-specific-row-in-pandas) but it deals with Boolean values. I didn't perfectly understand the answer but to my understanding it does not work in a similar manner with multiple categorical values. Also I cannot convert to boolean since I will be having multiple options in the color categories.

Comment: What if there are 2 green in `first` before a green in `second`. Will these 2 greens get the same `t_second` values? And I assume you want to do this to all colors, not just green?

Comment: Yes, same t_second is the expected result if it is the next occurrence after each row. Green is fine for now but I believe it will work for each color anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by one-hot encoding the `second` column:

```py
>>> pd.get_dummies(df.set_index("t")["second"])

   green  red
t            
1      0    1
2      0    1
3      0    1
4      1    0
5      0    1
6      1    0
7      0    1
8      0    1
```

And then multiply `green` and `red` with `t` so that we essentially break `t` into `green` and `red`:

```py
>>> _ * df["t"].to_numpy()[:, None]

   green  red
t            
1      0    1
2      0    2
3      0    3
4      4    0
5      0    5
6      6    0
7      0    7
8      0    8
```

Now if we fill the zeros with the *next non-zero* value, we will get the desired result.

```py
>>> # fill 0 with the next non-zero value #

   green  red
t            
1      4    1
2      4    2
3      4    3
4      4    5
5      6    5
6      6    7
7    nan    7
8    nan    8
```

This means that as of `t = 1`, the next appearance of `green` is at `t = 4`. We now only need to join this to the original dataframe to get what we want.

---

### Code:

```py
tmp = (
    pd.get_dummies(df.set_index("t")["second"])
    .mul(df["t"].to_numpy()[:, None])
    .replace(0, np.nan)
    .bfill()
    .rename_axis(columns="second")
    .stack()
    .rename("t_second")
)

df.merge(tmp, how="left", left_on=["t", "first"], right_on=["t", "second"])
```

This assumes that `t != 0`, which is likely the case for your real data.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a backward fill of the column?

Find the values where the condition is true:

```
dfx.loc[dfx["second"] == "green", "t_second"] = dfx["time"]
```

```
   time  first second  t_second
0     1   grey    red       NaN
1     2  green    red       NaN
2     3    red    red       NaN
3     4   grey  green       4.0
4     5  green    red       NaN
5     6   grey  green       6.0
6     7  green    red       NaN
7     8    red    red       NaN
```

Backward fill:

```
dfx["t_second"] = dfx["t_second"].bfill()
```

```
   time  first second  t_second
0     1   grey    red       4.0
1     2  green    red       4.0
2     3    red    red       4.0
3     4   grey  green       4.0
4     5  green    red       6.0
5     6   grey  green       6.0
6     7  green    red       NaN
7     8    red    red       NaN
```

Select the `first` green rows:

```
dfx.loc[dfx["first"] == "green"]
```

```
   time  first second  t_second
1     2  green    red       4.0
4     5  green    red       6.0
6     7  green    red       NaN
```